# Grab value from html dropdown list, to pass into javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

1)The user will click the button after each list.
2)onclick the button will send the selected value to a javascript function
3)I want to take the value in the javascript function and send to a php file using ajax

**Question** How do I send html selected value to a javascript function using onclick?

```
<select id="list"> 
      <option value=" ">Select a Name </option>
      <option value="Comfy">Comfy</option>
      <option value="Tough">William Tough </option>
      <option value="Soft">Soft</option>
</select>
<button onclick="updateDB(this.querySelector('list'.selected))">Click Me</button>

<select id="list2"> 
      <option value=" ">Select a Name </option>
      <option value="Comfy">Comfy</option>
      <option value="Tough">William Tough </option>
      <option value="Soft">Soft</option>
</select>
<button onclick="updateDB(this.querySelector('list2'.selected))">Click Me</button>
```

Javascript function:

```
function updateDB(number)
{

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

    xmlhttp.open("GET","/updatequery.php?numbers",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: $resultset = oci_execute($stid2); var_dump($resultset);

Comment: @Cagy79 `oci_execute()` returns `bool`. @Nameishi Check examples for how to fetch http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php.  Did you look anywhere before asking?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Correct!

Comment: oci should be for oracle not for mysql  .. remove improper tag and add the right one

Comment: $resultset = oci_execute($stid2);  tells me invalid character

Comment: Why the downgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the PHP documentation on OCI: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php

You need to fetch the rows from the database once you executed the select query.

An example here that should get you started:

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Comment: So you have to use a loop ? even if the outcome is just one element?

Comment: @Nameishi: No, you don't.

Comment: @AbraCadaver  could I use  $data2 = array();               $result = oci_fetch_all($stid, $data2, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

Comment: @AbraCadaver can you send me a link that would help? point me in right direction please